# How to reuse logic code for an android view?

Tags: android

I am coming from iOS. I want to create a picture slider and instantiate it different activities. I want to reuse the code that controls the slide and detects the gestures, so I can just instantiate the same class in each activity.

In iOS I do that by just adding controller logic in a view that I instantiate. How would I do that in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a few days of googling and thinking outside of the iOS mindset I found the solution, which ironically was the same as iOS.

Extend the View class. You can also extend a fragment but that has its own tradeoffs, mainly being that you can't instantiate a fragment inside another fragment. So to not limit your reuse of the class extend views. The downside to that is that with views you need to manage states, meaning that if the user rotates the view, you need to be able to store and restore the state of your view items (text view contents for example).

These links might help you out
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIArVywQe8k
    http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html
    http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html